# How to get a substring from a large string?

Tags: c#

I have a large string in the form of a query, like for example: 
"SELECT column_name1, column_name2, column_name3, column_name4 FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.field1 = table2.field1" (the original query will have about 30 column names from joins of about 6-8 tables)

Now I just want the column names from this string. How can I achieve that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you think of any algorithm on your own that might be helpful as a starting point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways including LINQ and RegEx but here's a process that uses string's Split function. Do note that this loop assumes that the column names will be pretty monotonic and will not assume special cases such as commas or spaces in column names.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MyClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<string> columns = new List<string>(); // columns collection

        string sql = "SELECT column_name1, column_name2, column_name3, column_name4 FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.field1 = table2.field1";
        string[] parts = sql.Split(new char[] {' ', ','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        for (int i=1; i<parts.Length; i++)
        {
            if (parts[i].Equals("FROM")) break;

            columns.Add(parts[i]); // add cols to collection
        }

        foreach(string column in columns)
            Console.WriteLine(column); // print out the columns
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this stand up to more complicated queries where those commas might exist in a subquery?

Comment: @Moo-Juice: No. I addressed that concern in my answer. 2nd sentence.

Comment: to Moo-Juice: Also, I do not need the column names from the sub query. All I need is the column names after the first 'SELECT' and before the first 'FROM'.
@PaulSasik: That is almost exactly what I could think of, but am still wondering if there is any better way. Thanks for this solution though. I just realized I wasn't thinking wrong.

Comment: @Baiju: Better is a very relative term. What are your worries and considerations? I did mention at the outset that you could do this with RegEx or LINQ. This process is much more imperative than LINQ but fairly straightforward.

Comment: @PaulSasik: I really appreciate whatever you have suggested and I am sure it does work perfect. In fact, I've already tried it. But like you mentioned that RegEx or LINQ can work too, and I have no idea how they work, so may be I want to try them to learn the methods (may be for a future problem). And again, I really am grateful for this solution of yours.

Comment: I have a small addition to this problem. What if I have alias names to the column names? like what if the problem string is changed to:
"SELECT t1.column_name1, t2.column_name2, t1.column_name3, t1.column_name4 FROM table1 AS t1 JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.field1 = t2.field1"???
Can just changing the loop from i=1 to i=2 and changing i++ to i+2 work??? Also splitting will now be done on ' ', ',' and '.'

Comment: I would keep the same loop but internally perform a second split call on '.' and take 2nd part if it exists other wise the first.

Comment: @PaulSasik: Thanks Sir. But now I have another tiny complication. Now my query string says "SELECT t1.column_name1, t2.column_name2, t1.column_name3 AS foo, t2.column_name3 AS bar FROM table1 AS t1 JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.field1 = t2.field1", meaning there could be more one tables (t1 and t2) using the same column name. In this case, I would like to save the alias names of the repeating column names (foo and bar) instead of the actual column names. Can you help me out with this. Thanks a ton again.

Comment: Please repost a new question based on this new requirement and link it back for here for reference.

Comment: @PaulSasik: I don't know why but people are down voting me on my new reposted question. Can you help me? I am a newbie and learning C# for my new project. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could use regular expressions or some ugly IndexOf stuff. Basic string and / or regex operations.

**Edit:**
You can find find infos regarding regular expressions on http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression - something like:

```
string resultString = null;
try {
resultString = Regex.Match(subjectString, "SELECT (.+) FROM", RegexOptions.Singleline  | RegexOptions.Multiline).Value;
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
// Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Comment: I am gonna try this to see if it satisfies my requirements. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Yikes.  Rough crowd.

```
        string query = "SELECT this, that, there, when, who, what, FROM Words";
        string[] split = query.Split(' ');
        string[] columns = new string[30];

        for (int i = 1; i < split.Length; i++)
        {
            if (split[i].ToUpper() == "FROM")
                break;
            columns[i - 1] = split[i];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think perhaps you're going about this in the wrong way.

If you're writing this SQL string yourself, then you already know the names, and should be constructing your SQL string from some kind of collection.

If you're not writing the string, then why not get the column names from the result set?  This presumes of course they have them (and aliases), and that it doesn't matter that you get the names AFTER the query is executed.

If you need to do this and you are writing this string yourself, then you need to dynamically construct the query so that you have some semblance of an idea when the data comes back out again.